# Can I run a external program with a python loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code to run a external program with python. The objective is to replace at each step of the loop values in one of the text files that are used by the external program (ctr3.npt), with values that are in the output of the program in the text file (tsr_1_seg6.txt). This codes works but it doesnt save at each step of the loop the values in ctr3.npt. If someone can help me, thank you.

```
N=5
for i in xrange(N):
    os.chdir( 'c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas' )
    os.system( '"C:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\w2.exe"' )
    shutil.move('tsr_1_seg6.opt', 'tsr_1_seg6.txt')

    data = np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\tsr_1_seg6.txt', skip_header=11, names=True)
    input=np.array(data['PO4'])

    trib =np.genfromtxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', skip_header=2, names=True)
    out=np.array(trib['PO4'])
    out[i]= input[i]*0.75
    trib['PO4']=out
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading the file you must write the data it once it is modified. At the end of your loop body add add call to `numpy.savetxt`. Something like, using the proper formatting, etc.

```
np.savetxt('c:\\Users\\Hidraulica\\Desktop\\w2furnas\\ctr_tr3.npt', trib)
```